# Jenkins: dynamic downstream jobs + Mercurial information

Tags: jenkins

I have a job which uses the Jenkins Mercurial plugin to get the revision and changes information, and based on the list of modified sources in the Mercurial repo it will launch a set of build jobs via jenkins-cli.jar. The launched builds are thus a dynamic list of downstream builds generated from the parent job, only externally.

How can I propapate the changelog information from this parent jpb so that changes and revision info can be viewed in these downstream jobs ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jenkins' REST API from the downstream job to get the information for the parent build.  The API can output XML, JSON, or Python marshaled output.  For example, to get the latest parent build data in JSON format, get the URL:

```
[your Jenkins URL]/[job name]/latest/API/json
```

The data includes a changeSet attribute which should contain all the changelog info you need.